# Styles applied with classlist.add does not apply in the browser, but the class gets added. Code bundled with Webpack

Tags: php, webpack, sass

I'm trying to transition a small project to use webpack. I'm very new to webpack and this is my first time using webpack. I have a situation where a classlist.add method that is run dynamically based on an event does add the class to the dom, but however the styles do not get applied. Please note that this css used to work without webpack using the sass compiler manually.

Here is my SourceCode

```js
class ThemeSetter{    
  constructor(buttonId){
        this.themeButton = document.getElementById(buttonId);
        this.themeSwitchHandler();
  }
  themeSwitchHandler = ()=>{
        this.themeButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
            const html = document.querySelector("html");
            const theme = html.dataset.theme;
            if(theme == 'dark'){
                html.dataset.theme = 'light';
                this.themeButton.classList.remove('toggleDark');
            }
            else{
                html.dataset.theme = 'dark';
                this.themeButton.classList.add('toggleDark');
            }
        });
    }
}
new ThemeSetter("darkMode");
```

```css
#darkMode{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:grey;
    height:2rem;
    width:2rem;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 2rem;
    border-radius:5px;
    i{
        transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    &.toggleDark i{
        color:green;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="darkMode"><i class="fas fa-adjust"></i></div>
```

Here is the Webpack Common Config File

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        loader: path.resolve(__dirname,"/src/js/pageload.js"),
        main: path.resolve(__dirname,"/src/js/index.js"),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname,"/src/indexT.php"),
            filename: "index.php",
            inject: "body",
            cache: "false",
        }),
    ],
    module: {
    }
}
```

Here is the WebPack Dev Config File

```js
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const {merge} = require("webpack-merge");
module.exports = merge(common,{
    mode: "development",
    output:{
        filename:'[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"dev"),
        clean:true,
        assetModuleFilename : 'img/[name][ext]',
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Here is the index.js file

```js
import {App} from "./modules/App";
import "../css/body.scss";
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands'
importAll(require.context('../img', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
App.init();
function importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);
  }
```

My guess here is that there is something to do with the SCSS compilation, but however, I observed that the required css is successfully preprocessed in the main.bundle.js.

```js
#darkMode {\\n  cursor: pointer;\\n  color: var(--grey-font);\\n  height: 2rem;\\n  width: 2rem;\\n  text-align: center;\\n  line-height: 2rem;\\n  border-radius: 5px; }\\n  #darkMode i {\\n    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out; }\\n  #darkMode.toggleDark i {\\n    color: green;\\n    transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

Please note that I'm not using webpack dev server since I use a PHP backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The SCSS code I have posted above selects the 'i' descendant of the parent that have the class "toggleDark". However, when importing FontAwesome through JS import, and after being preprocessed through webpack, the "i" element is replaced with an SVG. So no styling is applied. So I changed the SCSS code to,

```js
#darkMode{
    cursor:pointer;
    color:var(--grey-font);
    height:2rem;
    width:2rem;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 2rem;
    border-radius:5px;
    svg{
        transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    &.toggleDark svg{
        color:green;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

Then it worked! Sorry for the trouble